# How I find drug_code sequence for each pateint in their treatment?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Experts, Even though every patient comes to the hospital for the treatment of the same disease, his/her sequence of treatment is slightly different based on their current conditions. Example: Few patients may need more pre-care/pre-medicines than other patients. Here our objective is how to collect all sequences of treatments and quantify those patterns. Please help me if you can. My Pandas knowledge is not enough for solving this problem :-(

Current Dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient: ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two','two', 'two','three','three', 'three'],    
                     'drug_code': ['011', '012', '013', '012', '013', '011','011', '012', '013'],        
                     'date': ['11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/14/2022','11/8/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/14/2022']})

df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

Result Dataset like to have to find pattern sequences:

```
code_patterns = pd.DataFrame({'pattern':['011-012-013','012-013-011'],
                             'frequency': [2,1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group by `patient` with concatenating `drug_code` values into sequences, then find counts of the same drug sequences among users:

```
drug_freq_df = df2.groupby(['patient']).apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x['drug_code']))\
    .value_counts().to_frame(name='frequency')\
    .rename_axis('pattern').reset_index()

print(drug_freq_df)
```

The output:

```
       pattern  frequency
0  011-012-013          2
1  012-013-011          1
```

Comment: You are a life saver and the best in the town. Appreciate all your help in this. God Bless!!!